# Blocking/unblocking vs sync/async

Tags: asynchronous, rx-java, blocking

I am reading a book on RxJava, and following is an exceprt from it in context of async vs sync:

> Thus, the actual criteria that is generally
>   important is whether the Observable event production is blocking or nonblocking,
>   not whether it is synchronous or asynchronous.

So what is the difference between blocking/nonblocking and sync/async?

Comment: Depends on which book is this. Those are two dimensions and can form a matrix: blocking-sync = thread.sleep, blocking-async = monitor.wait, non-blocking-sync = any calculation, non-blocking-async = continuations

Comment: Book is 'Reactive Programming With RxJava"..by Ben Christensen.

Comment: Keep reading. Blockingness means: do you sacrifice a thread  to wait for a signal to happen. Async-ness means does your dataflow go around to multiple threads.